# Username + Password Wifi Login doesn't work on Lubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, password, thinkpad

Full disclosure I'm a linux newbie.  I recently installed Lubuntu 19.10 on my Thinkpad T560 (duel boot with Windows 10).  Lubuntu has no problems with my home wifi, but with my university's wifi where you need to enter your username AND password, Lubuntu doesn't display any window for entering a username or password when I click on it, simply nothing happens.  I've played around with my wifi settings and searched online but I have extremely limited wireless network knowledge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  And I do apologize for my newbieness and ineptitude at solving what is probably a trivial problem for experienced linux users.

Comment: Do you have pop-up windows enabled in your web browser? Are you sure that it's not popping up a new window behind your current window? Which web browser are you using right now? What happens if you try another web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu's default Wi-Fi GUI does not support networks which require both a username and a password. You should install the package `network-manager-applet` and copy `/usr/share/applications/nm-applet.desktop` to `~/.config/autostart` so that it starts when you log in.